# Is Sqlite database persistent for android system apps on Device Wipe / Factory Reset

Tags: android, sqlite, cloud, android-sqlite, android-backup-service

I am developing an application for android devices,later this will be shipped with the android device as a system app. This app has SQLite database implemented in it and later it may have some data in it.So my question is that, if user wipe his/her device the SQLite database will be wiped or not.

Comment: if the app data is wiped then data stored in sqlite will be wiped :)

Comment: @PreethiRao: he is talking about resetting the device. And by the way, system apps cannot be uninstalled, so the data of a system app cannot be lost by trying to uninstall it.

Comment: @PreethiRao: But as we can see for contacts app , all contacts deleted on device reset. So my concern is that, will my SQLite data be persistent or not because later on  I will add some data to the database. please give your valuable suggestion...

Comment: @ZygoteInit i understood what he wanted to do, But even in system app you can clear the cache datas and other datas without uninstalling the app .

Comment: @PreethiRao: of course you can. What Vikas was asking was would the data be preserved if the phone was reset, i.e. is there a special rule for system data that doesn't apply to third-party apps, and the answer is that the same rule applies to ALL SQLite db files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "wipe" you mean a factory reset or a manual OS install, then yes, all data including system data such as contacts, settings, **everything** is most certainly erased.

**EDIT:**

Google provides a [cloud backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) service for system or third party apps to restore user data on reset. See also the [**Using the Backup API**](http://developer.android.com/training/cloudsync/backupapi.html) tutorial for the implementation.